# MYSQL query - get penultimate delimited value

Tags: mysql

My recordset has a field which contains these values:

```
Product Tree 1->Product Tree 2->Product Tree 3->Product Tree 4
Product Tree 1->Product Tree 2->Product Tree 3
Product Tree 1->Product Tree 2->
```

I want to return the penultimate delimited value using '->' as a delimeter.
So in my example, the first row would return 'Product Tree 3', the second 'Product Tree 2' and the third Product Tree 1.  I can't use PHP for this purpose, it has to be done in MYSQL.

I started experimenting with SUBSTRING_INDEX.
I found that:

```
SELECT REPLACE( SUBSTRING_INDEX( 'Product Tree 1->Product Tree 2->Product Tree 3->Product Tree 4', '->', 3 ) , 'Product Tree 1->', '' ) AS header
```

returns 'Product Tree 2->Product Tree 3' and therefore gives me the next delimited 2 values after the first 'Product Tree 1'.

But how would I go about getting the penultimate delimited value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kind of strange format to keep that data in for a relational database.  Suppose you could just use [string functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index) and do this:

```
SET @foo = 'Product Tree 1->Product Tree 2->Product Tree 3->Product Tree 4';

SELECT substring_index(substring_index(@foo, '->', -2), '->', 1);
```